# Error 'Get-WmiObject : Invalid class "Msvm_ImageManagementService"'

Tags: powershell, wmi, windows-server-2012-r2

Recently I've been getting this error, and I have no idea what triggered it. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I found regarding this class is minimal and I'm not sure what I need to check or where to look in order to understand it and fix it.

System:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Preview Build 9431
- PowerShell Version 4.0 32bit and 64bit

Output:

```
PS > Get-WmiObject -Class "Msvm_ImageManagementService" -Namespace "root\virtualization"

Get-WmiObject : Invalid class "Msvm_ImageManagementService"
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Class "Msvm_ImageManagementService" -Namespace "root\virtualizati ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: End of server support say 2012, so it it removed it R2.

Comment: @magicandre1981, So this class is not available/supported in 2012R2? Also made an edit to the question.

Comment: I don't have a Server 2012 R2 running, so I can't check it.

Comment: HyperV? I believe 2012 / Win 8 has some dedicated HyperV cmdlets...

Comment: @AthomSfere, how can I find this out? It seems that way, but I just can't find any specific documentation.

Comment: Starting point at least http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846767.aspx

Comment: @AthomSfere Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any helpful information.

Comment: What information are you trying to get get? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559.aspx has the commands which likely require PowerShell 3

Comment: @AthomSfere First I'd like to find out if this class is still supported under 2012R2. If so, why am I getting the error of invalid class, and how to fix it. I have PSVersion 4.0

Comment: PS 4 should be OK, but with end of support it is possible even if it is there the WMI classes are slightly different thus through the errors.
My personal experience / preference is to use the most precise tool available tool, and avoid WMI whenever possible.

Comment: do you run it under correct PS version (64bit vs 82) I had similar and this was the case

Comment: @cpoDesign It is a 64 bit PS running.

Comment: @slybloty can you run it under 32bit instead? (just to humor me) had issues that it was mistargeting

Comment: @cpoDesign Same result.

Comment: @slybloty have you installed powershelll for HyperV, http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#install.cmd

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The class is still there, it now resides in a different namespace. It's in the namespace "root\virtualization\v2". It's also worth noting that the class has changed, previously used methods may not exist anymore.